# How to show regular expression validation message after focus is moved out of the textbox in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Below is my code, i have email textbox and phone number textbox in controller's view.
The problem is when user started typing, it shows the regular expression validation message, what i want is to show this message after user type complete email or phone number.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

this is code on view

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Seller_Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Seller_Email, new { placeholder = "Email" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Seller_Email)
        </div>
```

this is code on model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                  @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                  @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                  ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
    [Remote("EmailExists", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email already exists. Please enter a different Email")]
    public string Seller_Email { get; set; }
```

[this is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgygL.png)

Comment: By default it will only show the error message when you tab out of the control (if you then tab back in it will show it on everykey stroke) so there is something else going on . But why are you not using the `[EmailAddress]` attribute for the validation which uses a far better regex than yours?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would result in that behavior is if your add `ModelState` in the GET method (e.g. you GET method has a parameter which is your model). Either that or you have a script that overrides the `validator` defaults.

Comment: In this case it is showing error as user started typing and i'm using regular expression validation on other fields too and the same thing is happen there too

Comment: There there is something else wrong in your code (see my last comment)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using DataAnnotationExtensions. It's available as a NuGet package, this will validate email addresses among other validators you may find useful. Use this instead of the regex expression which won't validate whilst you are typing -

http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Answer (score -2):

1) Use the `onblur()` function and validate it in jQuery.

2) Remove the model validation.

Comment: That doesn't stop the validation that's currently in place.

Comment: But it still makes no sense. The question is: using MVC, which ties neatly into jQuery validation, how can one prevent the validation to kick in _while_ typing? Your answer: remove the validation and add jQuery validation. An answer like that doesn't really help.